# Mysql table join records from 2 tables but get all records even the ones with empty fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables and want to get all records from table '***klanten***' and where the '***automaten***' records are matching *bedrijfs_id*.

this is what i have so far.

```
$sql = "
SELECT 
`automaten`.automaat,
`automaten`.th_nummer, 
`klanten`.bedrijf, 
`klanten`.bedrijfs_id, 
`klanten`.plaats 
FROM klanten, automaten 
WHERE (`klanten`.bedrijfs_id = `automaten`.bedrijfs_id) 
ORDER BY `klanten`.bedrijf ASC 
";
```

resultin in:

```
+------------+-------------+-----------+--from automaten--+------------+
153509       |  Amigo      | Smilde    |  Hot Rocks       |  6170155   |
153509       |  Amigo      | Smilde    |  Cash Attack     |  6410031   |
153512       |  Boekanier  | Steenwijk |  Red Hot Active  |  6980051   |
153512       |  Boekanier  | Steenwijk |  Turboplay       |  6550298   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
bedrijfs_id  |  bedrijf    | plaats    |  automaat        |  th_nummer |
+------------+-------------+-----------+------------------+------------+
```

table klanten
bedrijf
bedrijfs_id
plaats
adres
telefoon
etc.

table **automaten**
*bedrijfs_id*
automaat
*th_nummer*

so I want to get even the records without any *automaat field*. (which has to be filled in then
Comment: improved formatting, corrected spelling
Mysql table join records from 2 tables but get all records even the ones with empty fields
I have 2 tables and want to get all records from table 'klanten' and where the 'automaten' records are matching bedrijfs_id.

Still no working solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to do a `LEFT JOIN` instead like

```
SELECT 
`automaten`.automaat,
`automaten`.th_nummer, 
`klanten`.bedrijf, 
`klanten`.bedrijfs_id, 
`klanten`.plaats 
FROM klanten
LEFT JOIN automaten 
ON `klanten`.bedrijfs_id = `automaten`.bedrijfs_id
ORDER BY `klanten`.bedrijf
```

Comment: this looks good!! 
But is it possible to get all in one result instead of 2?
153509 - Amigo - Smilde - Hot Rocks - 6170155
153509 - Amigo - Smilde - Cash Attack - 6410031
these like so:
153509 - Amigo - Smilde - Hot Rocks - 6170155 - Cash Attack - 6410031

Comment: @richardvansoest, NO, if there are multiple matching records then they will be presented as separated rows but You may try group_concat() but that won't give the result as you expect.

Comment: I wil give that a try 
case is: I have customers(klanten) with café and the have 2 gambling machines(atomaten) so i want to get a list of al the Customers and wich Automaten they got in one row.

Comment: I have put the table automaten inside the klanten table

Answer (score 0):

This should be your solution:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
    `automaten`.automaat,
    `automaten`.th_nummer, 
    `klanten`.bedrijf, 
    `klanten`.bedrijfs_id, 
    `klanten`.plaats 
FROM klanten 
LEFT JOIN automaten 
ON `klanten`.bedrijfs_id = `automaten`.bedrijfs_id
 ORDER BY `klanten`.bedrijf ASC 
 ";
```

Regards
V

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a left outer join:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Your query will look like:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(`automaten`.automaat),
`automaten`.th_nummer, 
`klanten`.bedrijf, 
`klanten`.bedrijfs_id, 
`klanten`.plaats 
FROM klanten
LEFT OUTER JOIN automaten 
ON `klanten`.bedrijfs_id = `automaten`.bedrijfs_id 
GROUP BY bedrijfs_id,bedrijf,plaats
ORDER BY `klanten`.bedrijf ASC
```

Comment: Thanks this works also but still get 2 results when there are 2 'automaten' on one klanten (means customer)

Comment: so you want only one automaat out of the two in the result. How do you decide which one you should expect in the output?

Comment: like in the same record with comma separated values?? Hot Rocks, Cash Attacks in this format?

Comment: Tryed that but then i dont see any `automaten` in the result

Comment: Have to go now, be back on this later today THANKS Neels !